# Is there a way to detect Phonegap's deviceready event from native code?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have a Phonegap app for Android where I need to call `sendJavascript()` in the first activity's `onCreate` method. From what I can gather, this doesn't work because by the time `onCreate()` is being executed, Cordova still hasn't loaded so the call won't go through. I've managed to get it working by making a new thread in `onCreate()` run `sendJavascript()` after sleeping for 2 seconds, but this isn't ideal for the task. `loadUrl()` also works except it takes focus away and I want this to work on iOS too.

Is there a way to call `sendJavascript()` from the native side after `deviceready` is fired from the Javascript side? I'm guessing not, but I just want some confirmation. Also if it's not possible, is there an alternative other than getting a thread to sleep for a few seconds?

Here's some example code of what I'm trying to do:

```
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        this.sendJavascript("javascript:something();");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can call a plugin after device ready is fired from javascript to native